# Replacing values in JSON using values from another file with jq

Tags: json, dictionary, jq, lookup-tables

I have a json file with city names in it and I would like to replace them with particular city codes from another file. The `data.json` is roughly:

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "CustomerName": "Customer1",
    "City": "Cityname1"
  }
}
{
  "RelevantObject": false
}
{
  "Customer": {
    "CustomerName": "Customer2",
    "City": "Cityname2"
  }
}
# {...
```

The code list can be anything that is the easiest to feed to jq, I've been trying with `codes.json`:

```
{
  "Cityname1": "Code1",
  "Cityname2": "Code2" 
}
```

but like I said, any format is fine. The hoped result:

```
{
  "Customer": {
    "CustomerName": "Customer1",
    "City": "Code1"
  }
}
{
  "RelevantObject": false
}
{
  "Customer": {
    "CustomerName": "Customer2",
    "City": "Code2"
  }
}
```

I've been trying to read the file in with `jq --argfile codes codes.json` but I've had a hard time of referring to the `$codes` in the `jq`:  `.Customer.City=$codes.?`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to a good answer here is:

```
.Customer.City |= $codes[.]
```

Comment: Apparently, if there is no `.Customer.City` I get an error: _Cannot index object with null_. I fixed it with `.Customer.City=( if .Customer.City==null then "empty" else .Customer.City )` and added an `empty` object to the `codes.json` but just for the record, is there a textbook solution (or even a textbook :) for that?

Comment: Please note that the only empty object in JSON is `{}`.  This is distinct from `null` and strings such as `"empty"`.

Answer (score 0):

```
jq --argfile codes codes.json 'select(.Customer?)|{(.Customer.City):$codes[.Customer.City]}' data.json | jq -n '[inputs] | add'
```

Comment: Please provide a description as to why your code is the solution